# How to get the data-value in a datalist?

Tags: javascript, php, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently coding a sports website with an editor of teams and players. My concerns are about the editor of teams.

I have a HTML input with a datalist which is built with an array.
I want to let the user choose between an exiting team (ID + Name), or write a new one. I chose to use the datalist, but the datalist doesn't work as a select object. For the datalist, for each option I put the ID in the attribute "data-value" and the name in the attribute value.

My problem is to get the data-value when I chose an option. When I choose an option it doesn't update the data-value of my input text.

```
<input name="Equipe" list="EquipeTest" type="text" id="Equipe" value="<?php echo $NomEquipe  ?>" data-value=<?php echo $IDEquipeJoueur?>"  >
<datalist id="EquipeTest">
<?php
for($k1 = 0; $k1<=$Compteur; ++$k1){   
echo "<option data-value='".$ListeEquipe[$k1]['ID']."' value='".$ListeEquipe[$k1]['Equipe']."' >".$ListeEquipe[$k1]['ID']."</option>";
}
?>
```

My goal is to get the ID in the $_POST instead of the value.
I try with javascript, but there is no possibility to add an event on an option. 
I can also get the value of the field and find the ID in the array... but it's not a good solution.

Thanks in advance,

J-E